# PHP foreach() supplied error

Tags: php, foreach

I have this code, I get an *Invalid argument supplied*:

```
<?php
include('php-riot-api.php');
$region = strtolower('euw');
$instance = new riotapi($region);
$grab_data = $instance->getSummonerByName('capn jacksparrow');
$decode_data = json_decode($grab_data, true);
$grab_id = $decode_data->{'id'};
$grab_dataB = $instance->getStats($grab_id);
$decode_dataB = json_decode($grab_dataB,true);
$unranked = '';
foreach($decode_dataB['playerStatSummaries'] as $summary) {
    if ($summary['playerStatSummaryType'] == "unranked") {
        $unranked = $summary;
        break;
    }
};

echo "wins: " . print_r($unranked['wins'], true);
?>
```

I get the following error: `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home1/tony1964/public_html/2v2tournaments/testing.php on line 11`

I tried using `foreach()` with an object rather than an array, but some people who used the site got an error, and others didn't - so this is where I'm at, at the moment.

**EDIT:**
I have now come up with this:

```
<?php
include('php-riot-api.php');
$region = 'euw';
$summoner_name = 'capn_jacksparrow';

$instance = new riotapi($region);
$get_name = $instance->getSummonerByName($summoner_name);
$find_id = json_decode($get_name);
$get_id = $find_id->{'id'};
$get_stats = $instance->getStats($get_id);
$find_unranked = json_decode($get_stats, true);

echo "get_name: ";
print_r($get_name);
echo "<br>find_id: ";
print_r($find_id);
echo "<br>get_id: ";
var_dump($get_id);
echo "<br>get_stats: ";
print_r($get_stats);
echo "<br>find_unranked: ";
print_r($find_unranked);
  $unranked = '';
  foreach ($find_unranked['playerStatSummaries'] as $summary) {
    if ($summary['playerStatSummaryType'] == 'unranked') {
      $unranked = $summary;
    }
    break;
  }
echo "<br>unranked: ";
var_dump($unranked);
var_dump($unranked->wins);
print_r($unranked);
?>
```

Now, I get the end result to be `unranked: string(0) ""` which isn't the result I am looking for, so I attempt to look at the unranked wins, I get the result `NULL`.

Heres the full result: http://2v2.lolnode.com/testing.php

Hopefully someone can figure out how to grab "unranked wins"

Comment: Have you checked the value of $decode_dataB['playerStatSummaries'] to make sure it contain what you expect?

Comment: var_dump($decode_dataB['playerStatSummaries']) and tell us what you get

Comment: @JohnConde `var_dump($decode_dataB['playerStatSummaries'])` = `NULL` Nope :/ It should contain an array

Comment: It means that `$grab_dataB` is probably empty, therefore `json_decode()` returns `null`.

Comment: @Jack Hmm, so somewhere along the line theres an error for example, could it be something to do with `$grab_id = $decode_data->{'id'};` ?

Comment: updated~ Hopefully this is slightly more helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [your output](http://2v2.lolnode.com/testing.php) there is:

```
[playerStatSummaryType] => Unranked
```

But your if statement looks like this:

```
if ($summary['playerStatSummaryType'] == 'unranked')
```

and:

```
'unranked' == 'Unranked' // => false
```

So, you have to change your if statement to:

```
if ($summary['playerStatSummaryType'] == 'Unranked')
```

Also, `break` should be inside the if statement like this:

```
if ($summary['playerStatSummaryType'] == 'Unranked') {
  $unranked = $summary;
  break;
}
```

With your current code the `foreach` will stop after one iteration and `$unranked` will still be empty.

Comment: I have changed it to `if ($summary['playerStatSummaryType'] == 'Unranked') {}` but I still get `unranked: string(0) "" NULL` for the results (updated website)

Comment: The `break;` should be inside the if statement. Now you break the `foreach` after one iteration.

Answer (score 1):

It means `$decode_dataB['playerStatSummaries']` is not an array

---

Try

```
if(is_array($decode_dataB['playerStatSummaries'])){
  foreach($decode_dataB['playerStatSummaries'] as $var)
         //Do something
}
```

Comment: It is an array? `$decode_dataB = json_decode($grab_dataB,true);` makes it into an array?